# I'm facing Compiler error in elixir, how can I resolve the below error?

Tags: elixir

for the look and say sequence problem, I faced the following issue.!

```
defmodule :look_And_say do
  def next_number(s,i) when i < String.length(s) do
    count = 1
    compare(s,i,count)
    next_number(s,i+1)
  end
  def next_number(s,i) do
   IO.puts("endd")
  end
  def compare(s,i,count) when i+1 < String.length(s) and s[i] == s[i+1] do
    compare(s,i+1,count+1)
  end
  def compare(s,i,count) do
    IO.puts str(count) <> s[i]
  end
end

IO.puts :look_And_say.next_number("11",0)
```

> (CompileError) look_and_say_sequence.exs:2: cannot invoke remote function `String.length/1` inside guard
>     (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
>     (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.

Comment: I've edited this to use text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, one cannot invoke arbitrary functions in guards. Only a limited subset of functions may be used in guards. Also, you cannot apply `Access` to strings (`[]` wouldn’t work on strings,) use [`String.at/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#at/2) instead.

You simply need to apply your condition within your function’s code

```elixir
def compare(s, i, count) do
  if i + 1 < String.length(s) and String.at(s, i) == String.at(s, i + 1) do
    compare(s, i + 1, count + 1)
  else
    IO.inspect({s, i, count}, label: "At the end")
  end
end
```